# How do I install Visual Studio 2015 on a Parallels 11 vm?

Tags: visual-studio, parallels

I've trying for days to instal Visual Studio Professional 2015 on Parallels 11, and I always get this same error message part-way through the process:

[image]

I have researched this and there were suggestions about moving the installer to a different location .... Didn't work. I've tried from ISO and from the files themselves.

Parallels 11, OSX Yosemite and El Capitain, Windows 10. I have VS2013 on there which is fine. The same ISO installed fine on my windows box.

Any suggestions very much appreciated.

Thanks,
Andy

**EDIT: an activity log from the installation is at http://pastebin.com/D3gz3LVq**  *thanks to @magicandre1981 :)*   Possible line of interest at line 146:

> The CTM file is out of date and should be deleted and rebuilt, but the file 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\1033\devenv.CTM' could not be deleted.

Comment: collect and share the log files: http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=8967043

Comment: Try ask on superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the Windows VM and reinstalled, everything fine now.

The old vm had VS 20101 and 2013, plus SQL Server 2012, already on and even though they should all be able to run on the same machine, I just had a feeling that there was some conflict somewhere.